# Settings for subdirectory WordPress installs on existing XAMPP WordPress localhost installs

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Have multiple WordPress installs working great on localhost XAMPP install on Win10Pro workstation.
Now trying to install WordPress into a subdirectory on one of those existing installs.  Not sure what settings to make given it is a new WordPress install in a subdirectory of a localhost Wordpress install on XAMPP; and, not sure of the proper syntax for the any ## entries in the xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts file, and any other files.  Also, what would be the proper syntax for the lines:  ServerName and ServerAlias in those entries???
I normally name those multiple names as name.dev.  Which adds the next question of, should I include the ".dev" part in the aforementioned entries???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer here is a link for your reference:

https://github.com/oliguo/Server-Deployment/blob/master/XAMPP.md#virtual-host-setup

Enable vhosts.conf on the etc/httpd.conf

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Add one more port what your another wordpress will be pointed.

```
#like website
listen 80
#like another website
listen 81
```

Then edit the vhosts.conf on the etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/website_a
  ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website_a/error_log"
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
  DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/website_b
  ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website_b/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart the xampp.